# What 'alternate grammar' does [[ appear in besides attributes?

Tags: c++, c++11

I don't understand this:

> (7.6.1) Two consecutive left square bracket tokens shall appear only when
>   introducing an attribute-speciﬁer. [Note: If two consecutive left
>   square brackets appear where an attribute-speciﬁer is not allowed, the
>   program is ill formed **even if the brackets match an alternative
>   grammar production.** —end note ] [Example: (slightly modified from source)

```
// ...
void f() {
int x = 42, y[5];
  // ...
  y[[] { return 2; }()] = 2; // error even though attributes are not allowed
                             // in this context.
}
```

What alternate grammar can `[[` be used for? Would the example be valid if attributes didn't exist (and what does the example do)?

Comment: I have a feeling it could end up much like the `>>` fiasco: technically required to be parsed a specific way, but over time leniency will arise and the standard may relax the constraint. That said, given the large number of situations attributes can be used in, it makes the compilers job much simpler to always parse `[[` as an attribute-specifier (which in turn makes the feature easier to get going).

Comment: @GMan: And it seems there is no other way than through lambdas to get a `[[` token outside of attributes.

Comment: @Xeo: I just Ctrl+F'd through the grammar of C++0x and that seems to be true. I'm not expert in attributes, and I don't think this would be valid, but here's a method that wouldn't need lambdas: `struct { void operator[](void*){} } x; x[[[blah]] new int];`. I don't think you can apply an attribute like that though, but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example creates a simple lambda, which is directly called and will just return `2`. This will get the third element from the array and assign it to `2`. Could be rewritten as follows:

```
int foo(){ return 2; }

int y[5];

y[foo()] = 2;
```

Or even

```
int y[5];

auto foo = []{ return 2; }; // create lambda

y[foo()] = 2; // call lambda
```

---

Now, if attributes didn't exist, the example would of course be well-formed, because the section you quoted wouldn't exist.

Comment: Oh! That makes sense. I'll leave this open for a while in case there are any other cases.

Comment: @Pubby: The reason `[]` was selected as the lambda inducer sequence was because there was no legitimate case where `[` could be used without an identifier or some other expression in front of it. So without lambdas, there's no way that `[[` could ever be a legitimate sequence of tokens.

Comment: Actually adding a pair of `()` should be enough to workaround it. `y[([]{return 2;}())] = 2;`